# ASP.NET "Cannot write to DB File" when logging in

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

please help me fix this.

I am setting up a ASP.NET website using a .mdb (Access) database file. I don't want to use SQL Server because I have to pay more for the hosting.

I followed this guide to get the .mdb file working in Visual Studio: http://imar.spaanjaars.com/404/using-the-microsoft-access-providers-to-replace-the-built-in-sql-server-providers
It all works fine when I run it on my local machine from VS 2008.

I have uploaded my website to my new web hosting and when I try to log in (using the ASP.NET login control) I am getting the message "Cannot write to DB File". It is not a proper error, but just a single line of text.

I have spoken to the web hosting company and they claim that all of the permissions are set up correctly.

I have been fiddling with web.config and so far no success.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Did the Web Hosting company tell you what permissions have been set? You need Modify permissions on the folder that contains the Access database. I say "you", I mean the user account that your application runs under - most likely the App Pool that your site runs in.

Comment: From memory, yes I think they set those permissions. Maybe they buggered it up. Is there anything else that could be causing this issue? I might give them a link to this page in my next email. Another thing they did for me was enable 32bit app support to the pool.

Comment: Looking at the source code of the provider, the only exception I can find that results in the message "Cannot write to DB File" is if the provider encounters an UnauthorizedAccessException (AccessConnectionHelper.cs, line 296) when trying to write to the database. So it is most definitely a permissions issue.